# How are Junctions evaluated?

Tags: raku

The idea of Junctions were originally introduced by Damian Conway in order to mimick Quantum superposition and express Quantum Computing algorithms.

As cute at this may be, the concepts of superposition and collapsing don't make sense in a programming context and the evaluations rules are far from being clear.

Comment: Did you read https://docs.raku.org/type/Junction at all? The evaluation rules are rather straightforward and consistent enough with any language that has a concept of broadcasting.

Comment: Note, the `R`-programming language has similar functions: `any` and `all` can be found/called as [S4 Group Generic Functions](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/methods/html/S4groupGeneric.html)

Comment: @raiph I discovered them after using Raku's identically named functions. They are generics in `R`'s OO S4 Class System. Yes they appear to be purely Boolean (more than that I cannot say). I mention them because persons interested in Raku junctions _might_ be expecting them to act similar to `R`'s functions.

Comment: @jubilatious1 **In `R`**: `any` or `all` read their arguments from left to right, returning `TRUE` if any or all of their args coerce to `TRUE`, and `FALSE` otherwise. And that's it. For example, `all(3,4) + any(5,6)` returns `2`, job done. That code is evaluated as follows. First, warnings about coercing values from double to logical. (The `3` and `4` of the `all`, and then just the `5` of the `any`.) Next, the `all` returns `TRUE`, then the `any` does too. Finally `TRUE + TRUE` yields warnings about coercing logicals to doubles (the two `TRUE`s to `1`s) and `2` is returned. **Job done.**

Comment: **In Raku**: `all(3,4) + any(5,6)` constructs a [conjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction) of `3` and `4`, a [disjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction) of `5` and `6`, and then adds them, yielding a new junction  `all(any(8, 9), any(9, 10))`. The code is evaluated as follows. The `all` constructs and returns an `all` junction, the `any` an `any` junction. These junctions are added and the result is a new junction that contains the additions. Note that no boolean anything was involved, and the junction must be further processed -- job **not** done.

Comment: @raiph you might be confusing utility with expectations. In `R`, `any(c(0:1))` returns `TRUE`;  similarly `any(c(FALSE, TRUE))` returns 
`TRUE`.  OTOH, we see that `all(c(0:1))` returns `FALSE` and similarly `all(c(FALSE, TRUE))` returns `FALSE`. Makes sense, no? And it's pretty easy to guess at the returns I ***haven't*** posted... .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254051/discussion-between-raiph-and-jubilatious1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a follow up on Hobbs answer and comments:

As it turns out, the distributivity behavior of the junctions is not the whole story. This is how the following expression would be evaluated if that were the case.

```
(1 | 2) + (3 & 4)

1 + (3 & 4)       ==> all(4, 5)
2 + (3 & 4)       ==> all(5, 6)

(4 & 5) | (5 & 6) ==> any(all(4, 5), all(5, 6))
```

but the actual evaluation produces:

```
(1 | 2) + (3 & 4) ==> all(any(4, 5), any(5, 6))
```

The junctive types affect the evaluation of an expression composed of more than one junctions.
The solution was found here: https://design.raku.org/S09.html#Junctions, which I'll just quote.

> If two or more arguments are junctive, then the argument that is chosen to be "autothreaded" is:
>
> - the left-most **all** or **none** junction (if any), or else
> - the left-most **one** or **any** junction
>
> with the tests applied in that order.
>
> Each of the resulting set of calls is then recursively autothreaded until no more junctive arguments remain. That is:

```
   substr("camel", 0|1, 2&3)
-> all( substr("camel", 0|1, 2),      # autothread the conjunctive arg
        substr("camel", 0|1, 3)
      )
-> all( any( substr("camel", 0, 2),   # autothread the disjunctive arg
             substr("camel", 1, 2),
           ),
        any( substr("camel", 0, 3),   # autothread the disjunctive arg
             substr("camel", 1, 3),
           )
      )
-> all( any( "ca",                    # evaluate
             "am",
           ),
        any( "cam",
             "ame",
           )
-> ("ca"|"am") & ("cam"|"ame")        # recombine results in junctions
```

Following these rules, `(1 | 2) + (3 & 4)` is evaluated as follows:

```
(1 | 2) + (3 & 4)

((1 | 2) + 3) & ((1 | 2) + 4)

(4 | 5) & (5 | 6)
```

The same rules also correctly derive the evaluation of the following expressions:

```
any(1, 2) + all(10, 20)
==>
all(any(11, 12), any(21, 22))

all(1, 2) + any(10, 20)
==>
all(any(11, 21), any(12, 22))


one(1, 2, 3) + any(4, 5)
==>
one(any(5, 6), any(6, 7), any(7, 8))

one(1, 2, 3) + one(4, 5)
==>
one(one(5, 6), one(6, 7), one(7, 8))

one(1, 2, 3) + all(4, 5)
==>
all(one(5, 6, 7), one(6, 7, 8))

one(1, 2, 3) + none(4, 5)
==>
none(one(5, 6, 7), one(6, 7, 8))
```

Those basic expression evaluation rules are completely missing from https://docs.raku.org/type/Junction, so the official documentation wasn't of any help.

**PS:**
Kudos to raiph for finding the answer too.

**EDIT:**

After reading this section https://design.raku.org/S09.html#Junctions, you would think that expressions containing junctions would be desugared at compile time with macros but that's not how it is done. Everything happens at run time but what happens in the `AUTOTHREAD` method below looks a lot like the macro expansion process.

### How are junctions evaluated?

- regular values (values of type Any, any value that isn't a junction) evaluate to themselves
- junctions (there are 4 junctive types: any, all, one, none) evaluate to themselves
- any(), all(), one(), none() (or their respective operators infix:<|>, infix:<&>, infix:<^>. none() does not have an associated operator) have their arguments evaluated normally and a junction value is constructed and returned. The type of the arguments (Any or Junction) is irrelevant.

(type really means type/subtype here)

- function calls where all arguments are of the type Any, or of the type Junction but with a corresponding parameter also of type Junction (or Mu) are regular function calls
- function calls with at least one argument of type Junction with a corresponding parameter of type Any have multiple dispatch failing and falling back to `method AUTOTHREAD(&call, |args)` in https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/main/src/core.c/Junction.pm6.

Below is a simplified (and mostly correct) translation of `AUTOTHREAD` in Perl.

Calling `infix:<+>(1 | 2, 3)` have the effect that `infix:<+>(1, 3) | infix:<+>(2, 3)` is returned and **that** process is really similar to macro expansion, which is possible because of the indirection created by the multiple dispatch and the fallback to `AUTOTHREAD`. This is both fascinating and horrifying.

```
sub AUTOTHREAD {
    my ($call, $args) = @_;
    my $positionals = $args->{list};

    sub thread_junction {
        my $pos = shift;
        my $junction = $positionals->[$pos];
        my @storage = $junction->{eigenstates}->@*;
        my @result;

        for (my $i=0; $i < @storage; $i++) {
            $positionals->[$pos] = $storage[$i];
            push @result, $call->($args);   # really multiple_dispatch($call, $args)
        }
        Junction->new(type => $junction->{type}, eigenstates => \@result);
    }

    for (my $i=0; $i < $positionals->@*; $i++) {
        my $arg = $positionals->[$i];
        if ($arg isa Junction) {
            if ($arg->{type} eq "all" || $arg->{type} eq "none") {
                return thread_junction($i);
            }
        }
    }

    for (my $i=0; $i < $positionals->@*; $i++) {
        my $arg = $positionals->[$i];
        if ($arg isa Junction) {
            if ($arg->{type} eq "any" || $arg->{type} eq "one") {
                return thread_junction($i);
            }
        }
    }

    my $named = $args->{hash};

    for my $key (keys $named->%*) {
        my $arg = $named->{$key};
        if ($arg isa Junction) {

            my $junction = $arg;
            my @storage = $junction->{eigenstates}->@*;
            my @result;

            for (my $i=0; $i < @storage; $i++) {
                $named->{$key} = $storage[$i];
                push @result, $call->($args);   # really multiple_dispatch($call, $args)
            }
            return Junction->new(type => $junction->{type}, eigenstates => \@result);
        }
    }

    $call->($args);   # really multiple_dispatch($call, $args)
}
```

Comment: Good follow-up! Now, if @raiph would just re-post his answer as well.  I'm curious!

Comment: I have downvoated this since it emphasizes the point that ```(1 | 2) + (3 & 4)``` produces ```==> any(all(4, 5), all(5, 6))``` which is different to ```==> all(any(4, 5), any(5, 6))```. This neglects the fact that these two forms are equivalent via [De Morgans laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

Comment: Yes I emphasized this because this is precisely how junctions are evaluated and how the spec that says that they should be evaluated, the spec is very specific about this, so it perfectly answers the question. The 2 junctions may always collapse to same boolean but they are structured differently, internally, and this is important to have an accurate mental model of them to better reason about them and eventually establish various algebraic properties they satisfy.

Comment: The junctive operator `&` has a higher precedence than the junctive operators `|` and `^` so this is an additional reason to emphasize that the `all()` and `none()` junctions are "autothreaded" first.

Answer (score 15):

A junction is just a set of values inside of a wrapper which is `any`, `all`, `one`, or `none` depending on the operator used to create the junction. We'll talk about the differences between the four types later; for the most part they behave exactly the same.

When you pass a junction to any function, method, or operator *except* those explicitly declared to take a `Junction`, the call is "autothreaded" and the result will be a junction. This is actually very simple and not at all quantum:
`(1 & 2 & 3) * 2` equals `1 * 2 & 2 * 2 & 3 * 2` equals
`2 & 4 & 6`, and `f(any(1, 2, 3))` equals `any(f(1), f(2), f(3))`. The order of items in a junction, as with a set, is insignificant, and Raku can, if it feels like it, evaluate autothreaded operations in parallel, so there might be more than one call to `f` going on at once.

When a junction is coerced to `Bool`, either by context or by an explicit operator like `so`, it becomes a single value. An `any` junction will be `True` if any of the values it contains are true, an `all` junction is true only if all of its values are true (including the case where it contains no values), a `none` junction is true if none of its values are true, and a `one` if *exactly one* value inside is true.

So suppose we have

```
my @words = <raku is fun>;
if all(@words).chars < 10 {
    say "nice short words";
}
```

this will print, because `all(@words).chars < 10` is the same as
`all('raku'.chars, 'is'.chars, 'fun'.chars) < 10`, which is
`all(4, 2, 3) < 10`, which is
`all(4 < 10, 2 < 10, 3 < 10)`, which is
`all(True, True, True)`, and `so all(True, True, True)` is `True`.

Likewise `so $num %% one(3, 5)` will be true if `$num` is a multiple of 3, or a multiple of 5, but not a multiple of 15.

Comment: Thank you, this is certainly clarifies Junctions a bit. I understand better why this particular expression produces its result. `raku -e 'say any(1, 2, 3) + any(10, 20);'` `any(any(11, 21), any(12, 22), any(13, 23))`
Maybe this should be a proper question, but can we say that junctions **distribute** (in the algebraic sense) the applied operator/function call and its arguments over the contents of the junction?

Comment: @WhiteMist yes. I haven't found clear documentation on that, but yes, it does distribute. The fun part is figuring out the logic behind the respective values of `any(1, 2) + all(10, 20)` and `all(1, 2) + any(10, 20)`.

Comment: @WhiteMist (and yes, I would encourage a question on that because I don't know the answer, and in any case it would probably be too much for this Q&A)

Comment: I've tested your examples `any(1, 2) + all(10, 20)` and `all(1, 2) + any(10, 20)`, the results are unexpeted and I have no idea of how they are derived.

This is why I unaccepted your answer. Your post talks exclusively about the distributive property of junctions, when you have an operator or function call with 1 junction and 1 or more normal values. That is the trivial part of how junctions work. But as we can see with your examples, the distributive model is not enough, the junctive type affect the result so they are clearly other implicit rules as to how junctions are evaluated.

Comment: Here are other non trivial expressions of junctions: `one(1, 2, 3) + any(4, 5)`, `one(1, 2, 3) + all(4, 5)`, `one(1, 2, 3) + one(4, 5)`, `one(1, 2, 3) + none(4, 5)`.

Comment: @WhiteMist. This is "the fun part" .@hobbs mentioned. Read "If two or more arguments are junctive ..." in the design doc section [Junctions](https://design.raku.org/S09.html#Junctions). FYI I had posted then deleted an answer to your question, but am considering undeleting it with a paste from that design doc section.

Comment: @raiph Yes that was it, I found out a little bit before you posted, I was about to give up. I really don't understand how this is not part of the docs. I happened to have refresh the page when you posted it so I have read your comment and even saved the webpage. I didn't know about the ethymlogy of the word "junction", that was interesting.

Comment: Nice example breakdown!

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer your questions and points in reverse order.

> Does a stack-based VM require an additional data structure for evaluating an expression containing [`Junction`s](https://docs.raku.org/type/Junction)?

No. Junctions are a very high level concept that almost the entire language is ignorant of. It just works, as follows.

That said, I'm always leery of thinking I know anything, so I did a few searches, and I think it may be helpful for me to share them:

- MoarVM has [2 code matches for "junction" in its github repo](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3AMoarVM%2FMoarVM%20junction&type=code). One is in a tool written in Raku. The other mentions "junction" in a comment in C code, but it's just a comment, not code, and I think it just means the idea of a C union type or somesuch.
- NQP, the virtual virtual machine also has [2 matches](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3ARaku%2Fnqp%20junction&type=code). They're all "conjuction", and none are related to Raku junctions.
- Even Raku doesn't really know about junctions. They are a built in type, but aren't really part of the true core language. In other words they're very loosely analogous to, say, `Date`.

> That is, in what way does the "classical" eval function (evaluate arguments, then call the function) need to be augmented to support the various types of Junctions?

I'd argue it isn't augmented at all.

> I would like a precise explanation of how expressions, conditionals and loops are evaluated when they contain Junctions within the context of imperative and functional programming.

Expressions don't get evaluated differently from, say, `42`.

That said:

- Raku supports ["truthiness"](https://docs.raku.org/language/glossary#Truthy_and_Falsy), and if a junction is boolean tested (eg used as an `if` condition) it evaluates to `True` or `False` (just as any other value, eg `42`, does). As a simple example, a `True | False` junction evaluates to `True`.
- If a function is applied to a list of arguments, one or more of the arguments might be a junction -- and if so, something like 99.9% of all built in and user functions will fail to bind to the list of arguments. For example, in the expression `(1 | 2) + 3`, the rhs argument of the function call (`+`) would successfully bind to `3` but the lhs won't bind, because `(1 | 2)` has no coercion to a number. But you don't get an error because there's a default fallback for functions (built in and user defined) that catches the dispatch, spots that one or more arguments are junctions, redispatches to the original function accordingly, and then gathers the results from the redispatches into a new junction that gets returned. For the example, `(1 | 2) + 3` results in a generic fallback function catching the call, and then redispatching to call `1 + 3` and `2 + 3` and gathering the result of each into a new *any* junction `any(4,5)` (equivalent to the literal `4 | 5`).

I will post this answer as is then fill this section out later to provide some more details given your request for "precise" details.

> As cute at this may be, the evaluations rules are far from being clear

It would be helpful if you shared what you've referenced in trying to understand them, eg the doc, or roast, or...?

> and the concepts of superposition and collapsing don't make sense in a programming context

FWIW they made (and still make) sense to me, but Larry felt those concepts were overkill for the types / functionality he wanted built in so he switched the vocabulary and functionality for them to the simpler concept of "junctions" in Raku, riffing off the concepts of [logical conjunctions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction) (cf an *and* junction) and [logical disjunctions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction) (cf an *or* junction) or similar notions. (Yes, the English use of "and" and "or" in that sentence was deliberate.)

> The idea of Junctions were originally introduced by Damian Conway in order to mimick Quantum superposition and express Quantum Computing algorithms.

As I understand it it was more about mixing a simple useful form of the constraint programming paradigm into the functional or imperative programming paradigms, and he thought the concept was the right one to promote to explain them. But Larry thought otherwise, at least for what he was willing to build into Raku, though the way he built it in actually makes it trivial to hook Damian's full approach into Raku anyway via a module.

Comment: Having returned here and read @WhiteMist's answer it felt appropriate to undelete this one; theirs sufficiently digs into the details I had "promised" and then felt I didn't have time/energy to nail down that my answer is no longer the distraction I worried it was, and has some value I think as a complement to their answer and .@hobbs'.